# Data Not Saving Instantly

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I have a registration form and a main form. the main form gets user data from sql sever. now if a new user should register and go to the main form, his/her details of registration will not be found on the sql database. the user will have to exit the application and run again before those details will be found. Please guys, why is this so? here is my registration code.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
  sqlcon.Open();
  SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("newuser", sqlcon);
  sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  // sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", 0);
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstname.Text.Trim());
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastname.Text.Trim());
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text.Trim());
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text.Trim());
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolID", Convert.ToInt32(cmbSchool.SelectedValue));
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Faculty", txtFaculty.Text.Trim());
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", txtDepartment.Text.Trim());
  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfilePic", "Default.png");
  sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  MessageBox.Show("Registration is successful\nYour Username is " + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "\nYour password is " + txtPassword.Text.Trim(), "Signed Up", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  main m = new main(txtUsername.Text);
  m.Show();
  this.Close();
}
```

This is how i retrive the details.

```
 void fillProfile()
    {
        int _schoolID;
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("ProfileView", sqlCon);
            sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Username);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sqlda.Fill(ds);
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            txtFullName.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString() + " " + dr["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
            txtDepartment.Text = dr["Department"].ToString();
            txtFaculty.Text = dr["Faculty"].ToString();
            txtMatno.Text = dr["MatNo"].ToString();
            txtPhone.Text = dr["Phone"].ToString();
            txtUserName.Text = dr["UserName"].ToString();
            _schoolID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SchoolID"].ToString());
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("GetSchoolByID", sqlCon);
            sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", _schoolID);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sqlda.Fill(ds);
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            txtSchool.Text = dr["SchoolName"].ToString();
        }
    }
enter code here
```

Comment: “... before those details will be found”? How are you finding those details?

Comment: Don't leave your connection open like that.  Put all those disposable data objects in a using {} block.

Comment: Just some feedback, but immediately logging people in is a bad idea. There should be another verification, like email, token, etc... if anyone can just register with no verification, it’s more vulnerable to bots registering random users, maybe posting bad things, corrupting your data, and maybe even posting illegal content with you not knowing who they are. Logging in after registration, not such a bad idea.

Comment: Also, if the user is automatically authenticated, he or she can possibly query all the usernames; such as, is common in LDAP or AD.

Comment: @Jesse thanks, i will add another verification. but right now, am stucked here if i cant find a way to get the registration details in main form after registration

Comment: @LarsTech will that help to resolve the issue?

Comment: Your code example shows how you are saving the data. How do you retrieve it? Have you confirmed (by looking in the database tables themselves) exactly when the data appear?

Comment: @DourHighArch the main form is supposed to get the users details from the database, but those details are not found after registration, the user will have to exit the app and run again before these details will be found.

Comment: How do you “get the users details from the database”? Post that code.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: @JohnWu i tried confirming using a datagridview while the program was still running but i found nothing. but after i re-run the app, the details came out

Comment: Thank you for your answer OP but what I meant was "What ***code*** do you use to retrieve it?

Comment: @JohnWu thats the code i use to retrieve it

Comment: What what triggers a call to `fillProfile`?

Comment: @JohnWu i called it in form load

Comment: Form_Load will usually only get called once (when you first load the form). Are you loading a new instance of the form after the update is completed?

Comment: @johnwu yes I am.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code while keeping an eye on the database table and noting if and when it changes. That should at least help you isolate the problem more. As it is, I am not sure we can tell if the problem is with the save, the load, or the display.

Comment: @johnWu okay thanks. I will do that.

Comment: @AdorableLaughter where is `fillProfile()` located and when do you fire it?